# How to use COUNTUNIQUEIFS in Goole sheets with an OR condition where a cell can meets two conditions

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, counting, count-unique

I'm trying to find the count of unique rows that meet multiple criteria in sheets. Data is like this:

```
ID |TYPE
1  |T1;T2;T3
2  |T1;T7
3  |T2;T3
4  |T6
```

I want a count of IDs where type is either T1 or T2. The right answer is 3 (ids 1,2 and 3 have either target type)

```
=countuniqueifs(A:A,B:B,{"*t1*","*t2*"})
```

gives me an answer of 2.

Any help greatly apprciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(IFNA(FILTER(A2:A, REGEXMATCH(B2:B, "T1|T2"))))
```

[image]

---

to avoid **T11** count in when the criterion is **T1**:

[image: 0]

Comment: Very creative combination of formulas.  The only issue is that the regex will match something like "T11".  I think it should be change to `=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, REGEXMATCH(B2:B&";", "T1;|T2;")))`